# Change the background of Plasma "Leave" dialog

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-background, plasma, 23.10, logout

```
Kubuntu 23.10 
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.110.0
Qt Version: 5.15.10
```

When pressing the "Log Out" shortcut or selecting the "Leave" option

[image]

[image]

I think it should look something like this, or so it did in Kubuntu 18.x:

[image]

as discussed [here](https://phabricator.kde.org/D11262#267850).

On the other hand, it might be the case that the background was removed in later Plasma: in Solus KDE with Plasma Version: 5.27.10 (KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0,Qt Version: 5.15.12) tere is no image, but there is a high level of transparency.

But in my case, no matter the theme I use, all the options appear on a dark gray background, with an almost imperceptible transparency. Can that be changed so that a wallpaper be set for this interface or that transparency be increased?

Comment: You might have either disabled the blur in the desktop effect plugin settings or KDE is not detecting your GPU. I've never seen background images on this ksmserver screen

Comment: @DanielT - I have edited the question: other Plasma systems also lack an image but the background is very transparent (tested on the same computer).

Comment: *To down-voters: please leave a comment on how to improve or clarify.*

Comment: @DanielT - Fixed it. It was indeed dependent on *level* of blur desktop effect: it applies only to transparent windows, but is by default set to "strong", which removes transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a semi-transparent window and as such it is affected by the "Blur" Desktop effect. This can reduce transparency if it's set too strong: decreasing its strength increases the transparency of these windows.

[image]

The image at Phabricator discussion linked in question is just the desktop wallpaper seen through a very transparent "Leave" window (that's why we see the panel and the desktop folders)

Comment: Wow! I didn't even realize that was missing. In my case I had to drag everything all the way left to "Light" for things to look right again. If it weren't for my transparent menus, I would even disable blur. It seems like a bug that 90% of the slider is undesirable.

Comment: @DanielT - The separate effect Translucency doesn't seem to affect *that* window though. But for others the Blur effect can be used in parallel with Background Contrast and Translucency effects. While the last can increase transparency, Blur reduces it, and, most usefully, Backround Contrast makes text readable on transparent windows (keeps the glassy effect but the background becomes more solid/readable). See [this](https://old.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/e4g7me/tip_you_can_just_use_breeze_for_blur_transparency/). Also, there is also Noise under Blur effect but don't know what that does.